# How to get OEM USB driver for Samsung Galaxy SIII with model number GT-I9300

Tags: android, mobile, galaxy, samsung-mobile

I want to get OEM USB driver for Galaxy SIII. I following this [official OEM USB Drivers page.](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html#Drivers) So I select OEM - Samsung and visit this [official Samsung website.](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/downloads) This website ask me to enter my model number so I write - "GT-I9300". But then I can't get anything. Can you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem following the same tutorial. I'm using Eclipse IDE, on a 64-bit Windows machine. This is how I solved it:

1. Theoretically, the USB driver for a clone version should be the same as a regular one, hence I´ve downloaded a [similar model](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/SCH-I535MBBVZW).
2. I had to configure a few environment variables to make ADB work ([tutorial](http://zacktutorials.blogspot.com.br/2013/04/adb-is-not-recognized-as-internal-or.html)).
3. Made the regular procedure: '*adb kill-server*' and '*adb start-server*'.
4. And finally, the most important one, while Eclipse IDE was open, I restarted the debug mode on my phone (just deselect an select again the option). In this step, on my phone, it asked me to confirm the connection!

I hope it works for you too. Sometimes the driver step might be skipped since Windows installed it automatically. I unistalled it and reinstalled several times.

Comment: Oh thank you very much. For that moment I've been trying throw genymotion. Everything now is working really good. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

find the drivers for Samsung SIII GT-I9300 USB debugging on this page
https://samsung-firmware.org/download/GALAXY%20S%20%E2%85%A2/9O12/INS/I9300XWUGML4/I9300ODDGML4/

under flashing requirements section
hope this helps.