# How to add Physical Android Device to Visual Studio 2015 Preview

Tags: android, android-activity, visual-studio-2015, native-activity

I have installed Visual Studio 2015 Preview and started new Project - Naive Activity Application (Android). I would like to run the application against physical device, but there is only emulator in the target. I can see from some [screenshot](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/11/12/introducing-visual-studio-s-emulator-for-android.aspx) that it is possible, but I cannot find the right way.

How to set the physical Android Device as the target?

Comment: Did you install the proper USB driver for your device?

Comment: Yes, you were right. A driver was missing. Now it shows the device automatically.

Comment: Well, it's the same when using Eclipse or Android Studio, so I thought that might be reasonably the problem.

Comment: In my case i had to restart the OS to update the device list. In case someone else forgets about this :)

Comment: And if you have the UK Samsung Galaxy S3 GT-I9300 then get the US Samsung Galaxy S III Verizon driver: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22228872/how-to-get-oem-usb-driver-for-samsung-galaxy-siii-with-model-number-gt-i9300 http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/SCH-I535MBBVZW

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked :
After making sure the required drivers are all installed, just connect your phone via usb
Wait until you see your phone's name instead of the emulator.
Connect!